# Replace all the spaces with ";"

Tags: c#, csv, replace

I'm making a CSV converter for this I need to replace all the spaces of my string with a ";". I've tried:

```
string content = tbxArret.Text;
string path = @"C:\Users\DanyWin\Desktop\CsvOutput\test.csv";
string[] space = new string[] { " " }; 

foreach (string contenu in content.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    content.Replace(" ", ";");
    File.WriteAllText(path, content);
}
```

But it didn't work. The text in the CSV file is just the copy of what I put in the content.

Example : a `string abc ="a b c ";` should return "a;b;c;".

Any help ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) don't change content it returns value. It should be:

```
content = content.Replace(" ", ";");
```

Comment: If you want to change content, use `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: Exactly, operation on a string are immutables, which mean that they never modify the original string, but return a new string.

Comment: Ty for your answer, it works. Now I've got another problem : all the spaces are replaced with a ";" but I have a multiline textbox and I need to put a ";" at the end of each line so that my program functions. How can I do that ? Example : Here is my string : string abc ="a b c\nc d e\n"; After the replace : string abc ="a;b;c;\nc;d;e;\n; @teo van kot